# Patient Interests in FHIR

Tags: hl7-fhir

Is there a good place to store patient interests in FHIR? (e.g. enjoy bike riding, scuba diver, etc..) I am considering using an Observation to capture this, but I wanted to make sure there wasn't another option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observation is appropriate.  It's a single point-in-time assertion.